# How can I make a launcher for ALT+TAB window switcher?

Tags: unity, compiz

I'd like to have an icon on the unity launcher that triggers either the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or *compiz scale* behavior. I don't want to use keyboard shortcuts and want to switch easily between applications using the mouse.

It would be great to trigger the compiz scale behavior by clicking an icon on the launcher.

Is it possible? What is the actual *command* that is run when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

You need a desktop file to put something in the launcher.

> gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/name.desktop

Fill out this template:

```
[Desktop Entry]
 Name=the name you want shown
 Comment=
 Exec=command to run
 Icon=icon name
 Terminal=false
 Type=Application
 StartupNotify=true
```

Then you need to learn about [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) which can simulate mouse and keyboard with commands.

Hope this helps even though I was not thorough.

Comment: you mentioned thanks her that means you got the answer right if you got the answer please mark it as a answer by clicking the tick mark below the arrows used to vote please!